# Get location data when out of service

Tags: ios, gps, location, cllocationmanager, gmsmapview

I'm working on a iPhone app that stores location data from a user. However, sometime the user doesn't have service.

**Is there an API that *estimates* location data when the phone gets back into service?** Or any other suggestions

Comment: I have similar problem. Can you please check it. How point is away from polyline. I need it to always on polyline. Interpolate will help but i don't know how to apply it on for solving this problem. Ignore red circle.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/d6sg3akexxe9xkh/GPS.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such API, because that would create wrong locations.
You have to write yourself such a method, that hopefully works in the scope of your application demands:

E.g You could do a linear interpolation when the GPS service has an outage for some seconds.

e.g:

A liner interpolation of lat and lon values work without special geographic calculations.

Just it would not work if you cross the datum limit (border longitude = 180E to 180 W),
and maybe not if you cross the poles.
But both situations will practically not happen.

Comment: I have similar problem. Can you please check it. How point is away from polyline. I need it to always on polyline. Interpolate will help but i don't know how to apply it on for solving this problem. Ignore red circle.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/d6sg3akexxe9xkh/GPS.png?dl=0

Comment: @anshul-systematix You should post a new question for your problem.